# countable product of totally bounded space is totally bounded

Tags: general-topology

Let $ \{ X_i  \}_ { i \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a countable collection of metric spaces $(X_i, d_i)$. The product topology on product space $X=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$ is equivalent to the metric topology on $X$ induced by
$$d(x,y) = \sum_{i}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \bar{d_i} (x_i,y_i) $$
where $\bar{d_i} (x_i ,y_i) = \min (d_i (x_i, y_i ) , 1) $ is the bounded metric for $d_i $ on $X_i$

I read that the countable product space $(X,d)$ is totally bounded if each factor space $(X_i, d_i)$ is totally bounded, but somewhat hard to prove this fact. Can anybody help me with that proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a ‘nuts-and-bolts’ proof.

Fix $\epsilon>0$; there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $2^{-m}<\frac{\epsilon}4$, and hence $\sum_{k\ge m}2^{-k}<\frac{\epsilon}2$. For $k<m$ Let $F_k$ be a finite subset of $X_k$ such that the open $\frac{\epsilon}2$-balls centred at points of $F_k$ cover $X_k$, and for each $k\ge m$ let $x_k\in X_k$ be arbitrary. Let

$$F=\prod_{k<m}F_k\times\prod_{k\ge m}\{x_k\}\;;$$

clearly $F$ is a finite subset of $X$. Now let $Y=\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be arbitrary. For each $k<m$ there is an $x_k\in X_k$ such that $d_k(y_k,x_k)<\frac{\epsilon}2$; let $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in F$. Then

$$\begin{align*}d(x,y)&=\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}2^{-k}\bar d_k(x_k,y_k)\\
&=\sum_{k<m}2^{-k}\bar d_k(x_k,y_k)+\sum_{k\ge m}2^{-k}\bar d_k(x_k,y_k)\\
&<\sum_{k<m}\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+1}}+\sum_{k\ge m}2^{-k}\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2\\
&=\epsilon\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$X=\bigcup_{x\in F}B_d(x,\epsilon)\;,$$

and $X$ is therefore totally bounded.

Answer (score 0):

In general, an *arbitrary* (i.e. not necessarily countable) product of *compact* spaces is compact (this is called Tychonov's theorem, one of the deepest theorems of mathematics). Now, using your notations, if $X_i$ is totally bounded then $\hat {X_i}$ (the metric completion of $X_i$) is compact. By Tikhonov's theorem, then, $\hat X = \widehat{\prod X_i} = \prod \hat X_i$ will also be compact, so the closure of $\prod X_i$ in $\hat X$ will also be compact. But this means exactly that $X$ is totally bounded ([compact metric space means complete and totally bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109550)).

The proof above has the disadvantage that it uses the axiom of choice (which is well hidden inside the proof of Tychonov's theorem). In the case of a countable product (as yours), the full power of Tychonov's theorem is not needed and one can circumvent it, thus also circumventing the use of the axiom of choice. A proof of Tychonov's theorem in this case (which almost proves your own question) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239885/tychonovs-theorem-in-countable-spaces).

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that topological closure of totally bounded space is totally bounded (thus compact). All the other part is clear for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Guldam: The topological closure of a totally bounded space is *compact* (which is even more than you asked for).

Comment: Closure of totally bounded sets is not necessarily compact

Comment: @YuiToCheng: This was 7 years ago, so I cannot recall what I meant to say, but I believe that I should have said "metric completion" instead of "closure". This should fix it, right? The completion of a totally bounded metric space is compact, I believe.